# TOAD vs AquaFold - Connecting to Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad, aquafold

does anyone have any experience using both of these products and willing to share some pros and cons of each? I love TOAD but I'm moving to Mac, so I'll have to give it away.  I can always run TOAD in a VM, but at the same time I'd like to try something new and native to Mac OS. Toad is a memory hog and crashes constantly, so if I could find anything with similar features and more stable I wouldn't mind the change.

I'm specifically concerned about code completion (Intellisense like), code formatting, SVN integration and the usual schema browsing, speed.  Toad has great speed and that's one thing I really like about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever settled on a good database GUI interface for Mac?

Comment: I "settled" with SQL Developer, yet I still use TOAD on a Windows VM a lot. Toad is super fast and responsive.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Sql Developer? You can download it free on the Oracle site: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html